# Saving previous AJAX response

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables, request, response

I'm doing AJAX-requests within an Intervalfunction in Javascript (e.g. once every 10 seconds).

I want to store the response (text ~ of the previous request) in a Javascript variable.

When the next request takes place, I want to check if the new response matches the previous one or not.

Something like:

```
var temp_data = response; //store response here
var final_data;

if(){
 final_data = temp_data;
} 
else {

}
```

Need soms advice/help,

Thanks!

Comment: if your ajax request are synchronous you can do that, or if your function is recursive

Comment: Could you provide code example perhaps?

Comment: of what synchronous  ajax or recursive function?

Comment: whatever you think would suit here best. and how I should compare those 2 responses

Comment: using a comparison operator of course, i chose neither, i would go with a server side implementation

Comment: any examples on how I can do the AJAX then and saving previous response each time?

Comment: i will give you a example tomorrow

Comment: Solved by storing responses in an array and slicing and adding objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by storing responses in an array and slicing existing and pushing new object.

```
if (ajaxResults.length < 2) { //As long as arraylength < 2
   ajaxResults.push(data); //Add object (executed for 2 objects)
} else if (ajaxResults.length == 2) { //
   ajaxResults.splice(0, 1); //Remove 1 object at index 0, next element that was in array goes to index 0
   ajaxResults.push(data); //Add last response to the end of array with push() = at index 1
}
```

Comment: so your ajaxes are synchronous